# Why no arcticle is needed here?

Tags: articles

Why no arcticle is needed in this sentence?

> In Germany (?) electrician killed a dog with an electric discharge.

Comment: An article **is** needed in that sentence. What is your source?

Comment: If this were a headline instead of a sentence, you could get away with no article. However, the headline would probably be written more concisely, and maybe even in the present tense, i.e., something like _German electrician kills dog with electric discharge_.

Comment: As a headline it would still be incorrect, the location would need to be moved to the end of the sentence. "Electrician killed [...] in Germany"

Answer (score 3):

It needs TWO (or three) things.

As you and StoneyB say, an article AND a comma.

> In Germany, an electrician killed a dog with an electric discharge.

OR

It needs a comma and a plural.

> In Germany, electricians killed a dog with an electric discharge.

OR

all of the above.

> In Germany, the electricians...

It all depends on what the author is trying to say explicitly. Regardless, it definitely needs some help.

Answer (score 1):

When you say something for the first thing or talk about something that is not particular, you use an indefinite article before a singular countable noun.

So the correct sentence is "In Germany, an electrician killed a dog with an electric
discharge".